# Authenticate to AKS Rest API with powershell

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, azure-aks

Trying to query the AKS REST API to get a list of my clusters using Invoke-Restmethod. How do I authenticate?

I've created an app registration and gave it access on the cluster resource. How do I pass the client ID, secret etc to the cmdlet? Or is there a better method available?

Thanks in advance.

Sameer

Comment: Azure AKS api are no different from any other Azure API, just follow the documentation! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure PowerShell commands to list your clusters through AKS REST API, there is no need to use Invoke-Restmethod. Here is the example code:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' -ServicePrincipal

Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path /subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters?api-version=2021-03-01 -Method GET
```

You can even use the Azure PowerShell command to get the list of the AKS cluster:

```
Get-AzAksCluster
```